# How do I capture a pattern that spans multiple lines with a Regex?

Tags: regex, vb.net

Please help. I've read dozens of Stack Overflow articles and online tutorials and can't figure this out!

I need a regular expression that is going to return a match that spans multiple lines and I'm not sure how to do it. For example the text is,

> 1) 11-JAN-2019 11:04 AM  I   RF   HQCSQT
>
> ```
>                     John Doe,Construction,555-555-5555,
>
> 2) 11-JAN-2019  1:42 PM  I   ADD  HQCSQT
>
>                     John Doe/Construction Worker Request El
>                     ectronic Add Wires: 7600SB=. Building c
>                     odes: ,
>
> 3) 11-JAN-2019  1:54 PM  I   ADD  STM003
>
>                     John Doe/Construction Worker Request El
>                     ectronic Add Wires: 1430SBX=. Building
>                     codes: ,
> ```

there are two matches that should come from the above string which is line 2 and line 3 up to the comma (","). See below for an example of a match.

> 2) 11-JAN-2019  1:42 PM  I   ADD  HQCSQT
>
> ```
>                     John Doe/Construction Worker Request El
>                     ectronic Add Wires: 7600SB=. Building c
>                     odes: ,
> ```

So I want to capture the regular expression pattern that starts with

```
^\d\)\s+\d\d-\w+-\d+\s+\d+:\d+\s+\w+\s+I\s+ADD\s+(HQCSQT|STM003)
```

and ends with the regex patter of

```
(,\s)$
```

Note: I tested "(,\s)$" and it is how the line ends when the multiline option is enabled.

Comment: Single-line mode: Dot matches newline (`\n`); Multi-line mode: `^` matches start of line (instead of start of string), `$` matches end of line (instead of end of string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already there.  You must not be setting the regex options properly.  You need to use both SingleLine and MultiLine modes at the same time.

```
Dim input As String = "
1) 11-JAN-2019 11:04 AM I RF HQCSQT

                    John Doe,Construction,555-555-5555,

2) 11-JAN-2019  1:42 PM  I   ADD  HQCSQT

                    John Doe/Construction Worker Request El
                    ectronic Add Wires: 7600SB=. Building c
                    odes: ,

3) 11-JAN-2019  1:54 PM  I   ADD  STM003

                    John Doe/Construction Worker Request El
                    ectronic Add Wires: 1430SBX=. Building
                    codes: ,
"
Dim pattern As String = "^\d\)\s+\d\d-\w+-\d+\s+\d+:\d+\s+\w+\s+I\s+ADD\s+(HQCSQT|STM003).*?,\s$"
Dim matches As Integer = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.Singleline).Count
Console.WriteLine(matches)  ' Outputs "2"
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying this now.

Comment: It works, you're great thank you! I'll mark this as the answer. I just always have trouble putting the anchors together. Do you have a good book or resource that taught you about anchors by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a recommendation.  I just learned through experience.  That and answering questions on here is good practice :)

Comment: Note to anyone trying this on regexstorm.net/tester, when you have the single and multiline options enabled there, it only returns 1 match. But if you plug this into Visual Studio, it returns 2 matches. I think it's because of the "RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.Singleline"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it can just be split by double new line :

```
Dim parts = Split(text, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

For i = 0 To parts.Length Step 2
    Debug.Print(parts(i) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & parts(i + 1) & vbCrLf & "------------")
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I'll try it but this method needs to be very accurate and I don't believe this is going to work but I will try it. I appreciate your response.